# apache2 not starting after purge and re-install

Tags: server, apt, apache2

First of all - I have looked and tried several approaches including
https://askubuntu.com/questions/94805/apache-server-not-starting/

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit**

I had purged using an answer at serverfault

- sudo service apache2 stop
- sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2 sudo apt-get remove apache2-common
- sudo apt-get autoremove
- whereis apache2 (gave 3 locations)
- sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2
- sudo rm -rf /usr/sbin/apache2
- sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/apache2

**I did**

- sudo apt-get -y install apache2 - says it is the newest version
- all conf files are in /etc/apache2 /etc/log/apache2/error_log is blank
- sudo service apache2 restart gives no output - no error - no message
- http//localhost or 127.0.0.1 say web server not available
- ps ax | grep -i apache gives 7919 pts/0 S+ 0:00 grep --color=auto -i apache

I am stumped - please help!

Edit - just realized /usr/sbin/apache2 does not exist
and neither does /usr/lib/apache2

After 3 re-installs - how do i get them - pleas help - thx

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In 14.04, the apache binaries are located in `apache2-bin`.

Since you are missing the binaries, you can try reinstalling that package along with `apache2`.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2 apache2-bin
```

Then try starting apache again, (Although I believe apache will auto-start itself after installation)

```
sudo apache2ctl start
```

Comment: Thx Dan! I wish I had known this but tasksel did the job for me...

Comment: How asinine. Surely installing apache2 should...install apache2. Thanks, Dan! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Apache2's binaries are in `apache2-bin`.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2*
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: i tried it, but had to add the `--reinstall` in the last command.

Answer (score 0):

thx for responding.

I did try the purge, autoremove and install

It installed file - echo'd a lot of stuff setting up conf and default sites but when i went to localhost - there was no web server

restart did not echo anything but still no webserver

What worked was was purging autoremove 
and

then sudo-apt-get install tasksel

sudo tasksel

and choosing lamp server

I suspect it had something to do me deleting /usr/sbin/apache2 and /usr/lib/apache2 using whereis apache2 by following blindly

### I wish I had known

sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2 apache2-bin

that probably would have fixed my problem but good to know

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the package using

```
dpkg -S /usr/sbin/apache2
```

after this, you get the response on the terminal like `apache2-bin: /usr/sbin/apache2`

then you re-install apache2 dependency **apache2-bin**

```
sudo apt install --reinstall apache2-bin
```