# error when install lamp-server^

Tags: server, apache2

I have update my ubuntu to 16.04 from 14.xx 
i try to go in to the page i have to se if all the code is safe.
Then i notice that the php  is not working, i install php7.0
after the installed in the terminal i whent back to the bage.
Doesent work :)

I uninstall my apache2 and everything with that.
I reinstall my apache2 and whent back to the page, and it doesent work :)

I uninstall the apache once more, and install the

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libhttp-message-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libencode-locale-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'rename' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libcgi-fast-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libwrap0' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhttp-date-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'perl-modules-5.22' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'liblwp-mediatypes-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libfcgi-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libcgi-pm-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaio1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libio-html-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'ssl-cert' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-data' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libperl5.22' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapr1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1-ldap' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-tagset-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'tcpd' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'liblua5.1-0' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-template-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libtimedate-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-bin' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php-mysql' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-utils' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-parser-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'liburi-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
libaio1 is already the newest version (0.3.110-2).
libapr1 is already the newest version (1.5.2-3).
libaprutil1 is already the newest version (1.5.4-1build1).
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 is already the newest version (1.5.4-1build1).
libaprutil1-ldap is already the newest version (1.5.4-1build1).
libcgi-fast-perl is already the newest version (1:2.10-1).
libcgi-pm-perl is already the newest version (4.26-1).
libencode-locale-perl is already the newest version (1.05-1).
libfcgi-perl is already the newest version (0.77-1build1).
libhtml-parser-perl is already the newest version (3.72-1).
libhtml-tagset-perl is already the newest version (3.20-2).
libhtml-template-perl is already the newest version (2.95-2).
libhttp-date-perl is already the newest version (6.02-1).
libhttp-message-perl is already the newest version (6.11-1).
libio-html-perl is already the newest version (1.001-1).
liblua5.1-0 is already the newest version (5.1.5-8ubuntu1).
liblwp-mediatypes-perl is already the newest version (6.02-1).
libtimedate-perl is already the newest version (2.3000-2).
liburi-perl is already the newest version (1.71-1).
libwrap0 is already the newest version (7.6.q-25).
rename is already the newest version (0.20-4).
ssl-cert is already the newest version (1.0.37).
tcpd is already the newest version (7.6.q-25).
apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9).
apache2-bin is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9).
apache2-data is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9).
apache2-utils is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9).
libapache2-mod-php is already the newest version (1:7.0+35ubuntu6.1).
libperl5.22 is already the newest version (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5).
mysql-client-5.7 is already the newest version (5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
mysql-client-core-5.7 is already the newest version (5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
mysql-common is already the newest version (5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
mysql-server-5.7 is already the newest version (5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
mysql-server-core-5.7 is already the newest version (5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
perl is already the newest version (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5).
perl-modules-5.22 is already the newest version (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5).
php-mysql is already the newest version (1:7.0+35ubuntu6.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Output of `sudo service apache2 status`

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since fre 2018-09-07 22:02:44 CEST; 9min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9559 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
  Process: 9551 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE

sep 07 22:02:44 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web serve
sep 07 22:02:44 apache2[9551]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 46: .: 
sep 07 22:02:44 apache2[9551]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 57: .: 
sep 07 22:02:44 apache2[9559]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 46: .: 
sep 07 22:02:44 apache2[9559]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 57: .: 
sep 07 22:02:44 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server
lines 1-15/15 (END)
```

I  still have : This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.

Pleasee can someone help me.

Comment: Have you started the apache? Try `sudo service apache2 start`.

Comment: I add sudo service apache2 start write my code, and nothing happends...Still error

Comment: Try this on terminal

Comment: I  have tryed it on terminal...

Comment: I try install again and this is what i get:

`$ sudo apt install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: Which *all code* you are talking about in the first line of question? The thing you posted in comments mean that apache2 is already installed. What is the output of `sudo service apache2 status`?

Comment: it cant be, i cant get my page in localhost or ip adress.'

`● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since fre 2018-09-07 22:02:44 CEST; 9min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9559 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
  Process: 9551 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE`

Comment: These lines clearly suggests that your apache2 service is inactive since 22:02:44 CEST. What do you get when you try `sudo service apache2 start`?

Comment: $ sudo service apache2 start
[sudo] password for Admin: 
$

Comment: It might help https://askubuntu.com/a/458422/816190

Comment: I search the internet yesterday, and find a solution, delete the apache2-common
And then i tried to install apache2 and it WORKS :)
Now can i access localhost..
Thanks for everyone that tried to help me.

Comment: That's great!! please include the steps you have taken in answer section and mark that as accepted.